# ADF "IF condition" is evaluating to false incorrectly

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a ADF Pipeline,

STEP 1 :

I am using to lookup activity to read the First row from File.
And After that Reading the Value in Variable I am using Set variable as below

```
@activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.Count
```

The Output of SetVariable is as below

```
{
"name": "var",
"value": "78"
```

}

Step 2 :
I have a if condition and I am Evaluating if the Value is 78 then do something else set the variable to false  as below :

```
@equals(variables('var'),78)
```

My if condition is evaluating the expression as false even we are getting 78 in the STEP 1

Answer (score 0):

SomeHow the value from the file is read as String
Simply putting a quotes around 78 resolved my issue

```
@equals(variables('var'),'78')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest something like your solution, but you fixed it first! :) I'm posting this to capture some more details for future readers.

ADF Pipeline variables only support String, Array, and Object types. In order to compare disparate values, you have to ensure they are the same type.

Solution 1 is to do what the author did, and treat the literal number as a String:

```
@equals(variables('var'),'78')
```

You could also cast it to a String:

```
@equals(variables('var'),string(78))
```

In this case, 78 could also be a dynamic value reference, like a JSON property.

Another option is to cast the String variable to int, like so:

```
@equals(int(variables('var')),78)
```

The pipeline expression language also contains a number of [other conversion options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#conversion-functions).